# How to show only sign out link in SharePoint site?

Tags: 2010

I have a requirement like below:
I need to show only sign out or log out link in a SharePoint site. I do not need to show out of box "My Settings" and "Sign in as as Different user" link. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a copy of Welcome.ascx file (under 12 hive\Template\ControlTemplates folder)
2. Rename it as CustWelcome.ascx
3. Find the tag with Personalization For Eg:
   `</SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat=”server” id=”ID_PersonalInformation”`
4. Change the Visible to false (if visible is missing add it and set it as false)
5. Now go to the master page and change the reference from welcome.ascx file to CustWelcome.ascx

You could find more details from [this post](http://ganpages.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/moss-2007-hide-my-settings-menu-item/)